# CSS "margin: 0 auto" not centering

Tags: html, css, centering

Okay I understand that this topic has been covered. But I have looked at various solutions and have had little success with them.

I just have no clue why this `margin: 0 auto;` is not working. I tried compensating the padding with `width: calc(33% - 40px);`, but this did not work.

Any help on why this is happening, with solutions would be greatly appreciated!

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
}

.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col-word {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 5px #000 solid;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  background-color: #A7F4F6;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class="col-1-3">
        <p class='col-word'>T</p>
        <p class='col-word'>V</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='grid'>
      <div class='col-1-3'>
        <div class='letter'>W</div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-1-3'>
        <div class='letter'>P</div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-1-3'>
        <div class='letter'>V</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xm2gvzbf/5/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is working.

The problem is you're centering a `div`, which is a block-level element by default, and which therefore occupies 100% width of its parent (`body`, in this case). So there's no space to move horizontally, hence no space to center.

For an illustration see this revised demo which has an added border around `.container`.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
}

.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col-word {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 5px #000 solid;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  background-color: #A7F4F6;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class="col-1-3">
        <p class='col-word'>T</p>
        <p class='col-word'>V</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class='col-1-3'>
        <div class='letter'>W</div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-1-3'>
        <div class='letter'>P</div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-1-3'>
        <div class='letter'>V</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you reduce the width of `.container` you'll see the centering work. Here's a second demo, with `width: 50%` applied to `.container`.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
}

.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col-word {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 5px #000 solid;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  background-color: #A7F4F6;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class="col-1-3">
        <p class='col-word'>T</p>
        <p class='col-word'>V</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class='col-1-3'>
        <div class='letter'>W</div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-1-3'>
        <div class='letter'>P</div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-1-3'>
        <div class='letter'>V</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that's helpful! But here's the catch. I do want it to be around 90%. Since the data presented on the page will vary considerably. Sometimes the data will occupy 90% of the page, while other data will occupy 20% of the page width.

Is there a solution to this?

Either way, I want it to look centered. I fear that forcing a fixed width like 500px. That it will not be responsive with various data.

Comment: You can make `.container` a flexbox, and then center the content.  Then you don't need to worry about `width` of `.container`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Answer (score 1):

It actually works, but without specifying the width it takes full 100%. Try something like:

```
   .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:50%;
    }
```

Hope this may help

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the width of the div for margin:auto to work. try to use width in percentage to make your div responsive as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a width on `.container` to let the `margin: 0 auto;` work. See the [updated JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xm2gvzbf/6/).

Answer (score 0):

Another fix that worked for me was to change the display for the parent  to display: inline in the CSS and set a max-width so that margin auto centers the text. So far, that has fixed the problem. Not sure if it's the best solution, but it's currently working. See the code below:

```
.parent-container{
    display: inline;
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 20px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an element which its display is block and its width is determined, we can center it horizontally with margin: sth auto;
Note: If width of the element equals the width of its parent the result could not be seen.