# How to center elements on the last row in CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am using CSS grid to layout some items like this...

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 16.666% 16.666% 16.666% 16.666% 16.666% 16.666%;
}

.item {
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

How can I get the last row to be centered instead of left aligned?  I can't guarantee the number of items so want to make the layout look right for any number of items.

Is this something I should be using flexbox for instead?  Or are CSS grids a suitable use?

Comment: Helpful Article: https://zellwk.com/blog/responsive-grid-system/

Comment: No...I don't think so *unless* you know the number of remaining items. You could then add a whole bunch of CSS rules to adjust the `column-start`. But,,,what is supposed to happen when there is an **odd** number of  left over items?

Comment: @fightstarr20 I don't think css grids are meant for that - its a 2D layout. In the example you have a layout that flows in one dimension - so use `flexbox`...

Answer (score 96, accepted):

CSS Grid isn't suited for alignment across an entire row because of crisscrossing tracks blocking the way. Here's a detailed explanation:

- [Aligning grid items across the entire row/column (like flex items can)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50234112/3597276)

As an alternative, use flexbox with `justify-content: center`.

This packs all items in the horizontal center of the row. Then your margins push them apart.

On fully-filled rows, `justify-content` will have no effect since [there's no free space for it to work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35817096/3597276).

On rows with free space (in your case, only the last row), the items are centered.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 calc(16.66% - 20px);
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 47):

Found a great article on how to [Control Leftover Grid Items with Pseudo-selectors](https://css-irl.info/controlling-leftover-grid-items/)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;  
}
.item {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background: #AB47BC;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Dealing with 2 orphan items */

.item:last-child:nth-child(3n - 1) {
  grid-column-end: -2;
}

.item:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n + 1) {
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

/* Dealing with single orphan */

.item:last-child:nth-child(3n - 2) {
  grid-column-end: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid grid--1">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid grid--2">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

That defeats the purpose of a grid system. A grid is a 2 dimensional array where everything has an X and Y value, like a spreadsheet.

Yes, you want a system where the items wrap. Flexbox fits the bill here because of `flex-wrap`.

```
#container {
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc((100px + (10px * 2)) * 4); /* item width + padding on either side times number of items */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

#container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0c0hzh8t/

This makes the children occupy all the available space, which if the row is full will be none and it'll be its standard size.

If you want the container to be sized automatically, then remove the `width` property and the container and its items will be resized automatically. It's just as well, but I assume you want to define the amount of items in a row.

Comment: It's a good explanation of why grid layout doesn't fit the OP's requirements. It really should have higher rating!

Comment: This is why it shouldn't be Grid vs Flexbox. Both have their use-cases.

Answer (score 7):

There is no specific property for making the last row behave differently than the previous ones.

Still, based on the fact that you define a set width that match *n* items within the viewport's width, you can use Flexbox and its `justify-content` property.

Set it to `center` and it will center the last row for any number of items.

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;                  /*  allow items to wrap  */
  justify-content: center;          /*  horizontally center items  */
}

.item {
  flex-basis: calc(16.666% - 20px); /*  subtract the margin from the width  */
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;           /*  make padding be included in the set width  */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

This should center any item inside row without using flex

```
.center-item {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

Comment: This seems to stretch a row to 100% width. As well, in a dynamic situation, you don't know which items are in the last row.

Comment: works perfectly when the number of items is fixed and is responsive too

Answer (score 1):

for grid item

```
grid-column: 1/-1;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

I really wanted a solution that wouldn't produce outside margins on the elements, instead using `gap`. I just multiplied the row gaps, then divided by how many items I want on the row - then subtracted from the width. Voila.

I realize it's not CSS grid, but flexbox is actually a better use case for staggered rows.

```css
:root {
  --marginXBase: 10px;
  --marginYBase: 10px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: flex-start;
  gap: var(--marginXBase) var(--marginYBase);
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
.item {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 15px;
  /* default to 3up */
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - (var(--marginXBase) * 2) / 3);
}
.x-2up {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - (var(--marginXBase) * 1) / 2);
}
.x-4up {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 calc(25% - (var(--marginXBase) * 3) / 4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item x-2up"></div>
  <div class="item x-2up"></div>
  <div class="item x-2up"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item x-4up"></div>
  <div class="item x-4up"></div>
  <div class="item x-4up"></div>
  <div class="item x-4up"></div>
  <div class="item x-4up"></div>
  <div class="item x-4up"></div>
  <div class="item x-4up"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for example for a 3-column layout with a seventh item:

```
enter .parent {
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:repeat(3,1fr);
gap:2rem; }


.child:last-child {
justify-self: center;
grid-column-start: span 3;
width: calc(32.9% - 1rem); }
```

Answer (score -1):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doichev-kostia/pen/yLjMYRW)

```html
  <div class="grid grid-cols-3 justify-items-center gap-2">
    <div class="w-5">1</div>
    <div class="w-5">2</div>
    <div class="w-5">3</div>
    <div class="w-5">4</div>
    <div class="w-5">5</div>
    <div class="w-5">6</div> 
    <div class="w-5">7</div>
    <div class="w-5">8</div>
    <div class="w-5">9</div>
    <div class="col-span-3">0</div>
 </div>
```

```css
.col-span-3 {
  grid-column: span 3 / span 3;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.w-5 {
  width: 1.25rem;
}

.grid-cols-3 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.justify-items-center {
  justify-items: center;
}

.gap-2 {
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem if the amount of containers is not fixed

Comment: item:last-child {
  grid-column: span 3 / span 3;
}

Comment: That still doesn't fix the problem. For example, it will look fine with 10 elements since you want to center the last one. It wont look good with 11 because you will have the 10th element alone in the left column and the last one under that one in the center.
https://jsfiddle.net/juh7stvp/14/

Answer (score -3):

I didn't work much on grids but as far as I know if you want to use Flex-box use this code.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
 }

.item {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 16.66%;
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Appreciate if useful. Ignore if not.

Answer (score -4):

This is my solution (as of April 23, 2018) for writing HTML emails:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-row-gap: 0;
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
  <div style="overflow: auto; height: 400px; margin-top: 15px;">
    <div style="position: relative">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="item"><div>Item 1</div></div>
        <div class="item"><div>Item 2</div></div>
        <div class="item"><div>Item 3</div></div>
        <div class="item"><div>Item 4</div></div>
        <div class="item"><div>Item 5</div></div>
        <div class="item"><div>Item 6</div></div>
        <div class="item"><div>Item 7</div></div>
        <div class="item"><div>Item 8</div></div>
      </div>
      <div style="position: absolute; bottom: -30px; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%;">
        <div style="background-color: #defabc; width: 300px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; cursor: pointer;">
          <span style="color: #000;">See all items</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What it does is, you're able to position items to the center at the very bottom of the grid wrapper. Again, like all other solutions, you can't put something inside a grid wrapper to be center-aligned in the very last row.

But at least this is a good alternative solution as a workaround.

Comment: Are you out of your mind using this for HTML Email? https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-display-grid/

Comment: When I was working on it, it was back in 2016, when it was working for the client I worked with who wanted this in their HTML campaign. At the time, I was just a recently new hire with no experience, and I had to struggle and figure things out. And yes, I am aware of what I wrote no longer applies to HTML emails nowadays. The CSS display grid you linked to now only works for nearly 50% of the email clients.