# Center children in a grid that don't fit column

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind and I have a grid layout and I want children that don't fit the column to be centered. I've tried `justify-items-center` and `place-items-center` but neither do anything.

e.g. In this [example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/lVGcAj0AdU) I want the bottom two to be centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will start by first replacing the `grid` with a `flex` instead because `grid` is not suited for alignment across an entire row. A detailed explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50234112/aligning-grid-items-across-the-entire-row-column-like-flex-items-can).

With that said, this is my suggested solution using `flex`.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="my-12 flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-4">
  <div class="h-64 w-48 rounded-md bg-black"></div>
  <div class="h-64 w-48 rounded-md bg-black"></div>
  <div class="h-64 w-48 rounded-md bg-black"></div>
  <div class="h-64 w-48 rounded-md bg-black"></div>
  <div class="h-64 w-48 rounded-md bg-black"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some pretty interesting and creative ways to center uneven elements on the last row of a CSS grid. They all try to get around the fact that CSS grid isn't the right solution to the problem though.

You can read more about why here: [Aligning grid items across the entire row/column (like flex items can)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50234112/aligning-grid-items-across-the-entire-row-column-like-flex-items-can)

The best approach would be to use flexbox instead.

---

Here's a rough demonstration: https://play.tailwindcss.com/37YqZZUE0o.

That may not be exactly the behaviour you had in mind but it can be tweaked as necessary to accomplish whatever you're going for.