# CSS grid layout last item center

Tags: html, css

I have a **grid layout** of 2 columns.  i have **5 div** , my **5th div** coming on **left** and i want my **5th div** to be **centered**.

How can i achieve that using any **grid property**?

**My Output:**

[image: My output]

**This is what I want:**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```html
<style>
        .container{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
            gap: 10px;
        }

        .box{
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: burlywood;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center elements on the last row in CSS Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276793/how-to-center-elements-on-the-last-row-in-css-grid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the last `.box` in your DOM to span across both columns.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.box {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container .box:last-child {
 justify-self: center;
 width: calc(200px - 20px);
 grid-column-start: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
</div>
```

The main piece of code to look at here is this:

```
.container .box:last-child {
 justify-self: center;
 width: calc(200px - 20px);
 grid-column-start: span 2;
}
```

`grid-column-start` tells the browser to render where the very left side of the `.box` start from based on your grid. Using `span 2` says that the `.box` will start from its natural position and span 2 columns.

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways to do it, but check out my code below with flexboxes.
`justify-content: space-around` made it center

```css
        .container{
            max-width: 500px;
            background: red;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            gap: 10px;
            align-items: middle;
            justify-content: space-around
        }

        .box{
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: burlywood;
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 200px

        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
    <div class="box">Lorem Lipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working for me.