# CSS Grids: automatic horizontal centering cells

Tags: css, css-grid, centering

I've a CSS grid with 3 columns based on a 12 columns layout. It could have from 1 single content (1 column 1 row) to many (resulting in a multiple columns multiple rows).
The CSS I'm using

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: var(--gap-vertical) var(--gap-horizontal);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

doesn't center horizontally che cells, for example, in a case like this:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Content 2
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the cells to be automatically horizontally centered in any case (from 1 content to many contents on many rows).

Below a case where I've just contents for 2 cells and what I want.

**Notice**: I have to handle this keeping the CSS Grids (no Flex or other).

[image]

Comment: beyond the image example can you post the code with an example ?

Comment: are you aware that you can simply use `1fr 1fr 1fr`? it the same as using `Xfr Xfr Xfr` for any X value

Comment: @SimoneRossaini added code example, very simple thing

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes you're right but that's another thing, it doesn't solve my actual issue

Comment: There's a problem with stackoverflow code snippet that it can't read ``justify-items``. You can use it to centralize your elements.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66596006/8620333

Comment: @AmirrezaAmini tried `justify-items: center;` but does nothing

Comment: No it does. ``justify-items`` is for grid and ``justify-content`` for flexbox.