# Balance amount of elements per row according to the screen width and number of items

Tags: css, css-grid

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46278350/5765312) to get the product cards centered at the last row for an online store, it works perfectly.

I would like to know if it's possible to define a method to equate the number of articles based on the total amount, obtaining the maximum number of articles per row, responsive and centering the entire group.

For example 11 items = 4 + 4 + 3 for wide screens
or 3 + 3 + 3 + 1 for narrow screens

This is what I have now:

[image]

This is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

I don't know the exact number of items each section will have, I'm looking for something generic for groups with even and odd content.

I know that a balance will not be possible for any quantity:

13 items = 5 + 5 + 3 / 4 + 4 + 4 + 1 / 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 2

I don't know if it's possible, any suggestions?

Trying to reason, if all the cards have the same width and margin, say 250px + 10px, maybe something can be done with measurements so that only items fit in each width.

For example:

3 items = row width = 790px

4 items = row width = 1030px

Comment: How are the elements supposed to be displayed if their number is equal to a [prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) (for example: 7, 11, 13, 17, etc.)? According to the presented logic, they will be displayed in one line.

Comment: No. This is not possible with CSS alone. You need javascript

Comment: This is what media queries are for.

Comment: @Paulie_D, yes media queries are ok, if you know the exact number of items each section will have...