# How to center a whole div in grid of odd number in css?

Tags: html, css, grid

I have this code

```css
.sec5-content {
  margin: 60px 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(275px, 1fr));
  color: var(--main-color-all);
  row-gap: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  column-gap: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.sec5-content>div {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class='sec5-content'>
  <div>
    <h1>1266+</h1>
    <h3>Members</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>81+</h1>
    <h3>Match Completed</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>1,20,1800+</h1>
    <h3>Revenue</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

This worked well to make responsive but, when I decrease the screen width then,
[image]

Here the lower div (Revenue div) is on the left and i want this in center. I tried justify-content , items and more it didn't work!

Any Solution!?

Comment: grid can't be used for this as it's a 2D layout. Switch to flex and justify-content center. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276793/how-to-center-elements-on-the-last-row-in-css-grid

Answer (score 0):

```
.sec5-content {
  margin: 60px 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  color: var(--main-color-all);
  row-gap: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  column-gap: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding commentary to explain what this does and the motivation behind the design choices you made.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use media query to align your grids accordingly for certain width

**FLEX SOLUTION**

Not sure if we can do this using grid, but if you choose to switch on flex, here is the ***temporary solution***, this might help you !!

```
<div class="sec5-content">
  <div class="sec51">
    <div>
      <h1>1266+</h1>
      <h3>Members</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>81+</h1>
      <h3>Match Completed</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="okay">
    <h1>1,20,1800+</h1>
    <h3>Revenue</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.sec5-content {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 3rem;
}

.sec51 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 3rem;
}

.sec51 > div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.okay {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the below CSS property in the CSS class hope that it will work.

**place-items:  center;**