# why margin property is not working?

Tags: html, css, margin

I would like to align contents of a class button into the middle on both horizontally and vertically.I used **`margin: auto`** property for that but which aligns the text vertically but not horizontal. I know it's possible to make it effective by using either `text-align` property or `display:flex`.but I just need a reason here about why the `margin: auto` property did not worked.I'm adding the snippet below.Thanks in advance.

Note **here it's working fine vertically the problem not working horizontally .so how it can be duplicate of not working vertically?**

```css
#main-body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 95%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: yellow;
}

#title-container{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
    background: red;
}

#button-container{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#data-container{
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.btn{
    width:25%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*margin:auto;*/
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*margin:0px;*/
}
.btn-text{
    margin:auto;
    /*float:none;*/
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main-body">
    <div id="title-container"></div>
    <div id="button-container">
      <div id="home-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Home</p>
      </div>
      <div id="update-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Update</p>
      </div>
      <div id="delete-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Create New</p>
      </div>
      <div id="logout-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Log Out</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="data-container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

i know it is possible to done using **`text-align:center;`**

```css
    #main-body{
        width: 100%;
        height: 95%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: yellow;
    }

    #title-container{
        width:100%;
        height: 10%;
        background: red;
    }

    #button-container{
        width:100%;
        height: 10%;
        background-color: blue;
        text-align:center;
        
    }

    #data-container{
        padding: 5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: blueviolet;
        
    }

    .btn{
        width:25%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        /*margin:auto;*/
        float:left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /*margin:0px;*/
    }
    .btn-text{
        margin:auto;
        /*float:none;*/
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main-body">
    <div id="title-container"></div>
    <div id="button-container">
      <div id="home-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Home</p>
      </div>
      <div id="update-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Update</p>
      </div>
      <div id="delete-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Create New</p>
      </div>
      <div id="logout-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Log Out</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="data-container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

it's also working fine with **`display:flex;`**

```css
#main-body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 95%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: yellow;
}

#title-container{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
    background: red;
}

#button-container{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: blue;
    display:flex;
    align-content:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

#data-container{
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.btn{
    width:25%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*margin:auto;*/
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*margin:0px;*/
    display:flex;
    align-content:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
.btn-text{
    margin:auto;
    /*float:none;*/
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main-body">
    <div id="title-container"></div>
    <div id="button-container">
      <div id="home-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Home</p>
      </div>
      <div id="update-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Update</p>
      </div>
      <div id="delete-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Create New</p>
      </div>
      <div id="logout-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Log Out</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="data-container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @caramba here the problem is just opposite.on this code it's working fine vertically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS "margin: 0 auto" not centering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817096/css-margin-0-auto-not-centering)

Comment: @ismail but here is just margin:auto; not margin:0 auto;

Comment: your element must have a width for centring element

Comment: there is no difference between margin:auto or `margin: 0 auto;` try to add width on `<p>` tag and check the `margin:0 auto;` remove top bottom margin also nothing else

Comment: @ismail i don't think that is a good idea to add a separate width to <p> element because,if i did not added a width to element <p> means which takes the whole width of it's parent.

Comment: [What, exactly, is needed for “margin: 0 auto;” to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955122/what-exactly-is-needed-for-margin-0-auto-to-work)

Comment: not the parent the 25% is fine try to give width to `.btn-txt` i.e 40px

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you are talking about and why can please explain with help of a snippet

Comment: @AfsalKhan tl;dr: the width of the p is the whole width of the window. Setting margins to auto doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

As I know that margin affects to element not content. If you set margin: 0 auto; it will place element to center of parent element.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you should note here.

1. content cannot be aligned vertically using margin: auto;
2. to align content align vertically you need to use some other ways, such as vertical alignment or using flexbox model etc.
3. if you want to align content horizontally center using margin: auto? then the width of the element should not be more than the content width.
4. if the content inside the element needs o be horizontally center aligned then simply use text-align: center;

for more reference on how CSS margin works please read the following description.

> The margin CSS property sets the margin area on all four sides of an
>   element. It is a shorthand that sets all individual margins at once:
>   margin-top, margin-right, margin-bottom, and margin-left.

for more in detail description: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Just to solve your problem with your existing code, check out following solution.

**CSS**

*class name changed from .btn-text to .btn-txt*

```
.btn-txt{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35817140/2724173 you child must have the width to work `margin:auto`

try to give width to `.btn-txt` i.e `40px` also there is the spelling mistake in your class is `btn-txt` and your css selector is `.btn-text`

```css
#main-body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 95%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: yellow;
}

#title-container{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
    background: red;
}

#button-container{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#data-container{
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.btn{
    width:25%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    /*margin:auto;*/
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*margin:0px;*/
}
.btn-txt{
    margin:10px auto;
    /*float:none;*/
    color: #ffffff;
    width:40px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main-body">
    <div id="title-container"></div>
    <div id="button-container">
      <div id="home-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Home</p>
      </div>
      <div id="update-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Update</p>
      </div>
      <div id="delete-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Create New</p>
      </div>
      <div id="logout-button" class="btn">
        <p class="btn-txt">Log Out</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="data-container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```